# Merge two sorted linked lists in-place using operator +

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list

I've been trying to merge two sorted linked lists without using any extra memory and I've tried to overload the + operator. I think I may not have understood the operator overloading that well or that maybe I am messing with some pointers that I am not supposed to mess with. 
I've also included the overloading of the operator << and >> because maybe I am messing with something there, tho I highly doubt it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct node{

    int value;
    node* next;

};
class LinkedList{

public:
    node *head, *tail;
    LinkedList();
    void AddElement(int);
    LinkedList& operator + (const LinkedList&);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const LinkedList&);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream&, LinkedList&);

};
LinkedList& LinkedList::operator + (const LinkedList& b){

    LinkedList c;
    node* temp_head;
    node* temp_a = head;
    node* temp_b = b.head;
    if(temp_a == NULL){
        temp_head = temp_b;
    }
    if(temp_b == NULL){
        temp_head = temp_a;
    }
    if(temp_a->value < temp_b->value){
        temp_head = temp_a;
    }else{
        temp_head = temp_b;
        temp_b = temp_a;
        temp_a = temp_head;
    }
    while(temp_a->next != NULL){
        if(temp_a->next->value > temp_b->value){
            node* temp = temp_b;
            temp_b = temp_a->next;
            temp_a->next = temp;
        }
        temp_a = temp_a->next;
    }
    temp_a->next = temp_b;
    while(temp_b->next != NULL){
        temp_b = temp_b->next;
    }
    c.head = temp_head;
    c.tail = temp_b;
    cout << c;
    return c;
}
LinkedList::LinkedList(){

    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

}
istream& operator >> (istream& in, LinkedList& l){

    cout << "New List" << endl;
    cout << "Number of elements in the list:" << endl;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int new_value;
        cin >> new_value;
        l.AddElement(new_value);
    }

    return in;

}
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& l){

    node* p = l.head;
    while(p){
        cout << p->value << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return out;

}
void LinkedList::AddElement(int new_value){

    // function that adds a new element at the end of the list
    node* q =  new node;
    q->value = new_value;
    q->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL){
        head = q;
        tail = q;
        q = NULL;
    }else{
    tail->next = q;
    tail = q;
    }

}
int main()
{
    LinkedList a, b;
    cout << "List 1." << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    cout << "List 2." << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << b;
    cout << (a + b);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `return c;` -- You are returning a reference to a local variable.  Undefined behavior.  Second, `operator +` should be returning a brand-new object, not a reference.  I would expect `+=` to return a reference.

Comment: None of the operators (in their normal prototype) is really a good fit for destructively modifying the second operand. I'd recommend a function.

Comment: Turn the warning on, turn them up loud and do not ignore them. Compiler error: Source code is syntactically incorrect and cannot be transformed into executable code. A compiler warning means the the source code is syntactically correct, it can be transformed into executable code, but it probably doesn't do what you want it to do. Warnings are your first line of defense against runtime errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operator + overload is returning a reference to an object you created in the overload. When you return from the overload, the object is destroyed, leaving you with a dangling reference. Turn on warnings as that should have been detected by your compiler.